# Postfix - all attachment extraction at the server side

Tags: node.js, email-attachments, postfix-mta

How can I extract all the attachments coming to the postfix email server? in order to save it to another (efficient) file server. I don't want to log in for every user and extract the attachments for the individual users but extract all the attachments (as file objects or file stream) as it comes to the postfix server and save it. While extracting, the routine should know which user an attachment belong but it should not go by user way. I specially want to avoid the login session/cycle.

As the second option - if I can get a push notification about a users attachment as it arrives. I am sure there are ways to do that - please let me know best ways to do it. And then extract attachment(s) for the user whose email with attachment(s) has just arrived. Still, I don't want log-in/out cycle to extract. It has to be done such a way that no individual password would be necessary.

Guessing lot of solutions would come in in python, thats great though. It would be also helpful if I get some NodeJS solution to do this.

Please help, and don't mix your solution with these two options - one at a time solution please - either one :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a thorough google for postfix, procmail and uudeview - That combo will allow you to save attachments on a file server.

As a starting point have a look here:

https://kuther.net/howtos/howto-receive-mail-and-save-attachment-fetchmail-procmail-and-metamail

...and here...

http://www.mugginsoft.com/content/postfix-automatically-decode-zipped-attachments

HTH

Regards
Frank